# R - Model specification for repeated measures GLMM (lme4)

Tags: r, time-series, lme4, mixed-models

I'm having some trouble correctly specifying my longitudinal model in R. My analysis is looking at gender differences in a score assessed at three time points. In effect, I want to see if either gender has consistently higher scores and/or a different rate of change. I understand that I'm trying to see if the intercept and/or the slope differ between genders, but I'm not sure how to structure the model/what to enter as a fixed or random effect.

Small example of my data:

```
'data.frame':   108 obs. of  10 variables:
 $ PNumber : Factor w/ 36 levels "P1002","P1004",..: 1 1 1 2 2 2 3 3 3 4 ...
 $ Sex     : Factor w/ 2 levels "Female","Male": 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 2 ...
 $ Visit   : Factor w/ 3 levels "V1","V2","V3": 1 2 3 1 2 3 1 2 3 1 ...
 $ V1      : int  1 0 0 1 0 0 1 0 0 1 ...
 $ V2      : int  0 1 0 0 1 0 0 1 0 0 ...
 $ V3      : int  0 0 1 0 0 1 0 0 1 0 ...
 $ TD      : num  0 0 0.1818 0.0909 0.3636 ...
```

Where 'TD' is the measured score, 'PNumber' is the ID variable, and 'Visit' denotes the measurement occasion.

From what I understand, the model to test for a difference in intercepts:

```
m1 <- lmer(TD ~ Sex + Visit + (1|PNumber), data=data)
```

And for slope:

```
m2 <- lmer(TD ~ Sex * Visit + (1+Sex|PNumber), data=data)
```

Do these models capture what I'm trying to assess?

I'd really appreciate any help in the right direction. I've only got a very basic understanding of R that I've cobbled together in the past few weeks, so I apologise if I'm missing something very simple.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

So, the level-1 groups are repeated measures (Visit), and the level-2 groups are individuals (PNumber). Here's what I would do (I think you're close):

Start with the unconditional model:

```
m1 <- lmer (TD ~ Visit + (~1|PNumber), data=data)
```

Then, allow change over time to be random at level-2:

```
m2 <- lmer (TD ~ Visit + (~Visit|PNumber), data=data)
```

Then, add gender to your model:

```
m3 <- lmer (TD ~ Visit + Gender + (~Visit|PNumber), data=data)
```

This will provide a fixed-effects estimate for gender that tells you whether gender is a significant predictor of higher scores.

Then, add the interaction between change over time and gender:

```
m4 <- lmer (TD ~ Visit + Gender + Visit*Gender (~Visit|PNumber), data=data)
```

This will provide a fixed-effects estimate for the interaction between change over time and gender that tells you whether the rate of change with respect to scores is significantly different between genders.

Comment: That's a great help, thanks. Just a bit of a novice question, why wouldn't I include gender as a random effect?

Comment: Since the level-2 units are individuals and since gender is measured at the level of the individual (at level-2), you can't include it as a random effect there. If you could, then it would tell us that gender varies across individuals, which isn't very helpful. If there were a third level (maybe individuals are grouped together) then you could include gender as a random effect at level 3.

Comment: I understand that perfectly now. Thanks for your help.

Comment: Sure thing. I found this book really helpful: http://www.amazon.com/Multilevel-Modeling-Statistics-Behavioral-Sciences/dp/1466515856/ref=sr_1_1?ie=UTF8&qid=1418670614&sr=8-1&keywords=multilevel+modeling+using+r

Comment: Could you please explain why "+(~Visit|PNumber)" and not "+(~1|PNumber)" or  "+(~PNumber|Visit)" or even "+(~1|Visit*PNumber)"?

Comment: I'll try to take a look tomorrow.